# How to add custom node field into page title?

Tags: nodes, theming, entities, 7

I have a custom node field I want to add into the page title. How can I do this?

Content type is a property listing and I want to have area size and location printed next to the title.

e.g. Large Mansion 900 sq ft (Chicago)

Location is also a taxonomy term in a dropdown list.

Do I need a preprocess_page function to extract the field and then use page.tpl.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `hook_preprocess_page` function in your template.php file would certainly be one way to do it:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if (isset($node->nid) && $node->type == 'article') {
    $data = $node->field_custom_field[$node->language][0]['value'];

    $vars['title'] = $vars['title'] . ' ' . $data;
  }
}
```

In page.tpl.php your `$title` variable should contain your new string based on the field.

You'll probably want to do a couple of extra checks in there as well, for example making sure the node is of the right type, etc.

**EDIT**

To address your comments I guess you'd want to do something like this:

```
$area_size = $node->field_area_size[$node->language][0]['value'];
$location = $node->field_location[$node->language][0]['value'];

$vars['title'] = "$vars[title] $area_size sq ft ($location)";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand now. Can you tell me how I would do it for a certain content type? I want to grab a $node->custom_field in a content type and change the page title.

Comment: @Chris I've added an extra bit to the `if` statement, you'll just need to change the bit inside the quotes to match the name of your content type

Comment: Thanks so much for that. Is there a way to keep the original title + field? I think that may be tricky.

Comment: You can just use the original title and tack it on the end, I've updated the answer again :)

Comment: Thanks for the code. Here is mine:

function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if (isset($node->nid) && $node->type == 'property_listing') {
 $variables['title_suffix'] = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_area_size');
  }
}


This works for me but I would like to add one more field onto the end of the 'field_area_size'. When I try add it on, I just get ArrayArray

Comment: Essentially, the content type is a Property Listing. I would like to have $title followed by field_area_size field_location, where area_size is an integer with suffix "sq ft" and field_location is in brackets. So e.g. Large Mansion 3500 sq ft (Meadow Lanes)

Comment: @Chris I've added another update I think it'll do what you're after

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2687/discussion-between-chris-and-clive)

Comment: With your code, I get a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

There's a module for that: [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title).

> This module gives you granular control over the page title. You can specify patterns for how the title should be structured and, on content creation pages, specify the page title separately to the content's title.

Comment: I believe the Page title only works for <title> tags in the <head>.. not the <body>.